# How to close firefox at a given time in linux?

Tags: linux, firefox

The challenge is to be able to close firefox at a given time, to protect a person from its own "internet addiction" and ensure some rest during the night.

In this case, my partner asked to shut firefox down at 22h00, as she was staying up at night and then the next day being tired.
And when she happened to want to open firefox after 22h00, close it automatically after 15 minutes from when she opened it.

**EDIT**

I've written this question with an answer in place already where I created a shell script and then integrated with linux file.

There in an error on the code thatif time is before 22h00, it still is adding 15 minutes.

```
now=$(date +'%R')
  KILL_DATE=$(date -d "22:00 today" +'%R')
  if [ "$now" > "$KILL_DATE" ]; then
     KILL_DATE=$(date -d "$now today + 15 minutes" +'%R')
  fi
  exec echo "pkill -f firefox" | at $KILL_DATE
  exec $MOZ_PROGRAM "$@"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: not about programming? what do you call setting up a shell script? That said..your options seem a good place to share this solution too. Thanks for refering.

Comment: @jww, added code to the question, given there was still an error there. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for this was to:

1. replicate firefox file on `/usr/bin/` to firefox_daytime
2. update the lines where firefox is loaded and use the "at" command to execute the background killing task at the specified time.

This was chosen because usually she opens firefox from the shortcuts on her "start menu".
This was only tested using openSuse.

specifically, the code for achieving this was:

```
  now=$(date +'%R')
  kill_date=$(date -d "22:00 today" +'%R')
  if [ $now -gt $kill_date ]; then
     kill_date=$(date -d "$now today + 15 minutes" +'%R')
  fi
  exec echo "pkill -f firefox" | at $kill_date
  exec $MOZ_PROGRAM "$@"
```

Which can be found on the last lines of the new file.

/usr/bin/firefox_daytime

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ***** BEGIN LICENSE BLOCK *****
# Version: MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0/LGPL 2.1
#
# The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License Version
# 1.1 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
# http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/
#
# Software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" basis,
# WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License
# for the specific language governing rights and limitations under the
# License.
#
# The Original Code is mozilla.org Code.
#
# The Initial Developer of the Original Code is
# Netscape Communications Corporation.
# Portions created by the Initial Developer are Copyright (C) 1998
# the Initial Developer. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Contributor(s):
#    Wolfgang Rosenauer <wolfgang.rosenauer@suse.de>
#                       <wr@rosenauer.org>
#
# Alternatively, the contents of this file may be used under the terms of
# either the GNU General Public License Version 2 or later (the "GPL"), or
# the GNU Lesser General Public License Version 2.1 or later (the "LGPL"),
# in which case the provisions of the GPL or the LGPL are applicable instead
# of those above. If you wish to allow use of your version of this file only
# under the terms of either the GPL or the LGPL, and not to allow others to
# use your version of this file under the terms of the MPL, indicate your
# decision by deleting the provisions above and replace them with the notice
# and other provisions required by the GPL or the LGPL. If you do not delete
# the provisions above, a recipient may use your version of this file under
# the terms of any one of the MPL, the GPL or the LGPL.
#
# ***** END LICENSE BLOCK *****

##
## Usage:
##
## $ mozilla [args]
##
## This script is meant to run a mozilla program from the mozilla
## rpm installation.
##
## The script will setup all the environment voodoo needed to make
## mozilla work.

cmdname=`basename $0`

##
## Variables
##
MOZ_DIST_BIN="/usr"
MOZ_DIST_LIB="/usr/lib64/firefox"
MOZ_APPNAME="firefox"
MOZ_PROGRAM="$MOZ_DIST_LIB/$MOZ_APPNAME"

MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER="$MOZ_DIST_LIB/$MOZ_APPNAME.sh"
if [ "$0" = "$MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER" ]; then
  [ -h "/usr/bin/$MOZ_APPNAME" ] && \
   _link=$(readlink -f "/usr/bin/$MOZ_APPNAME")
  if [ "$_link" = "$MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER" ]; then
    export MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER="/usr/bin/$MOZ_APPNAME"
  fi
else
  export MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER="/usr/bin/$MOZ_APPNAME"
fi

mozilla_lib=`file $MOZ_PROGRAM`
LIB=lib
echo $mozilla_lib | grep -q -E 'ELF.64-bit.*(x86-64|S/390|PowerPC)' && LIB=lib64

BROWSER_PLUGIN_DIR=/usr/$LIB/browser-plugins
if [ ! -d $BROWSER_PLUGIN_DIR ]; then
  BROWSER_PLUGIN_DIR=/opt/netscape/plugins
fi

MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="$MOZ_DIST_LIB"
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MOZ_DIST_LIB${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# needed for SUN Java under Xorg >= 7.2
export LIBXCB_ALLOW_SLOPPY_LOCK=1

##
if [ -z "$MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH" ]; then
  export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=$BROWSER_PLUGIN_DIR
else
  # make sure that BROWSER_PLUGIN_DIR is in MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH
  echo "$MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH" | grep "$BROWSER_PLUGIN_DIR" 2>&1 >/dev/null
  _retval=$?
  if [ ${_retval} -ne 0 ]; then
    export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=$MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH:$BROWSER_PLUGIN_DIR
  fi
fi

# disable Gnome crash dialog (doesn't make sense anyway)
export GNOME_DISABLE_CRASH_DIALOG=1

moz_debug=0
script_args=""
pass_arg_count=0
while [ $# -gt $pass_arg_count ]
do
  case "$1" in
    -d | --debugger)
      moz_debugger=$2;
      if [ "${moz_debugger}" != "" ]; then
        shift 2
        moz_debug=1
      else
        echo "-d requires an argument"
        exit 1
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      # Move the unrecognized argument to the end of the list.
      arg="$1"
      shift
      set -- "$@" "$arg"
      pass_arg_count=`expr $pass_arg_count + 1`
      ;;
  esac
done

if [ $moz_debug -eq 1 ]; then
  tmpfile=`mktemp /tmp/mozargs.XXXXXX` || { echo "Cannot create temporary file" >&2; exit 1; }
  trap " [ -f \"$tmpfile\" ] && /bin/rm -f -- \"$tmpfile\"" 0 1 2 3 13 15
  echo "set args ${1+"$@"}" > $tmpfile
  echo "run" >> $tmpfile
  echo "$moz_debugger $MOZ_PROGRAM -x $tmpfile"
  exec $moz_debugger "$MOZ_PROGRAM" -x $tmpfile
else
  now=$(date +'%R')
  kill_date=$(date -d "22:00 today" +'%R')
  if [ $now -gt $kill_date ]; then
     kill_date=$(date -d "$now today + 15 minutes" +'%R')
  fi
  exec echo "pkill -f firefox" | at $kill_date
  exec $MOZ_PROGRAM "$@"
fi
```